# Convert emoji Unicode byte sequences to Unicode characters with jq

Tags: json, unicode, jq

I'm [filtering Facebook Messenger JSON dumps](https://dev.to/dandv/how-to-extract-your-facebook-messenger-messages-from-a-conversation-2nik) with `jq`. The source JSON contains emojis as Unicode sequences. How can I output these back as emojis?

```
echo '{"content":"\u00f0\u009f\u00a4\u00b7\u00f0\u009f\u008f\u00bf\u00e2\u0080\u008d\u00e2\u0099\u0082\u00ef\u00b8\u008f"}' | jq -c '.'
```

Actual result:

```
{"content":"ð¤·ð¿ââï¸"}
```

Desired result:

```
{"content":"‍♂️"}
```

Comment: The problem is that the console is interpreting those backslash sequences. `echo '{... \\u00f0 ...}'` to correct it… Of course in reality you probably wouldn't be working with copy-pasted literals in the console, right…?

Comment: It's not the console, but the fact that each UTF-8 byte is encoded as a separate Unicode code point. `content` is mapped to a string that needs to be explicitly decoded.

Comment: Seems a little premature to be redirecting readers of your blogpost to this question for a solution, no?

Comment: Embedding UTF-8-encoded strings in JSON when JSON already supports arbitrary Unicode seems like a strange design choice, at best.

Comment: This is incorrect JSON. The spec doesn't allow you to encode Unicode this way; the spec requires UTF-16 values for code points with `\u`, not UTF-8 byte sequences. It's possible to write a parser, maybe even partially using jq, that would decode this and re-encode it correctly, but is there any way to fix the sending side to properly encode this? (For full details, see Section 9, String: https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's *incorrect*, but it's less direct than it could be.

Comment: The specification also doesn't require a processor to automatically decode the UTF-16 surrogate pairs, so the problem of reconstructing the actual code points they represent would remain.

Comment: Is this really the JSON you receive? Or is an array of bytes you have copied out of the debugger? If so, you're wasting a lot of time with a debugger artifact.

Comment: @Codo: yes. You can test by exporting Facebook messenger chats after sending a "" to Zuck.

Answer (score 3):

@chepner's use of Latin1 in Python finally shook free in my head how to do with jq almost directly. You'll need to pipe through iconv:

```
$ echo '{"content":"\u00f0\u..."}' | jq -c . | iconv -t latin1
{"content":"‍♂️"}
```

In JSON, the string `\u00f0` does not mean "the byte 0xF0, as part of a UTF-8 encoded sequence." It means "Unicode code point 0x00F0." That's ð, and jq is displaying it correctly as the UTF-8 encoding 0xc3 0xb0.

The iconv call reinterprets the UTF-8 string for ð (0xc3 0xb0) back into Latin1 as 0xf0 (Latin1 exactly matches the first 255 Unicode code points). Your UTF-8 capable terminal then interprets *that* as the first byte of a UTF-8 sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the response contains the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode code points, not the code points themselves. `jq` cannot decode this itself. You could use another language; for example, in Python

```
>>> x = json.load(open("response.json"))['content']
>>> x
'ð\x9f¤·ð\x9f\x8f¿â\x80\x8dâ\x99\x82ï¸\x8f'
>>> x.encode('latin1').decode()
'\u200d♂️'
```

It's not *exact*, but I'm not sure the encoding is unambiguous. For example,

```
>>> x.encode('latin1')
b'\xf0\x9f\xa4\xb7\xf0\x9f\x8f\xbf\xe2\x80\x8d\xe2\x99\x82\xef\xb8\x8f'
>>> '‍♂️'.encode()
b'\xf0\x9f\xa4\xb7\xf0\x9f\x8f\xbf\xe2\x80\x8d\xe2\x99\x82\xef\xb8\x8f'
>>> '‍♂️'.encode().decode()
'\u200d♂️'
```

The result of re-encoding the response using Latin-1 is identical to encoding the desired emoji as UTF-8, but decoding doesn't not give back precisely the same emoji (or at least, Python isn't rendering it identically.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jq-only solution.  It works with both the C and Go implementations of jq.

```
# input: a decimal integer
# output: the corresponding binary array, most significant bit first
def binary_digits:
  if . == 0 then 0
  else [recurse( if . == 0 then empty else ./2 | floor end ) % 2]
    | reverse
    | .[1:] # remove the leading 0
  end ;

def binary_to_decimal:
  reduce reverse[] as $b ({power:1, result:0};
       .result += .power * $b
       | .power *= 2)
  | .result;

# input: an array of decimal integers representing the utf-8 bytes of a Unicode codepoint.
# output: the corresponding decimal number of that codepoint.
def utf8_decode:
   # Magic numbers:
   # x80: 128,       # 10000000
   # xe0: 224,       # 11100000
   # xf0: 240        # 11110000
     (-6) as $mb     # non-first bytes start 10 and carry 6 bits of data
                     # first byte of a 2-byte encoding starts 110 and carries 5 bits of data
                     # first byte of a 3-byte encoding starts 1110 and carries 4 bits of data
                     # first byte of a 4-byte encoding starts 11110 and carries 3 bits of data
   | map(binary_digits) as $d
   | .[0]
   | if   . < 128 then $d[0]
     elif . < 224 then [$d[0][-5:][], $d[1][$mb:][]]
     elif . < 240 then [$d[0][-4:][], $d[1][$mb:][], $d[2][$mb:][]]
     else              [$d[0][-3:][], $d[1][$mb:][], $d[2][$mb:][], $d[3][$mb:][]]
     end
   | binary_to_decimal ;
```

```
{"content":"\u00f0\u009f\u00a4\u00b7\u00f0\u009f\u008f\u00bf\u00e2\u0080\u008d\u00e2\u0099\u0082\u00ef\u00b8\u008f"}
| .content|= (explode| [utf8_decode] | implode)
```

Transcript:

```
$ jq -nM -f program.jq
{
  "content": ""
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need a font which supports this.

You are confusing Unicode composed chars with UTF-8 encoding. It has to be either:

```
$ echo '{"content":"\u1F937\u200D\u2642"}' | jq -c '.'
```

or

```
$ echo '{"content":"\u1F937\u200D\u2642\uFE0F"}' | jq -c '.'
```

Comment: The mojibake in the question has nothing to do with *fonts*. And your solution also suffers from the Unicode escape sequences being interpreted by the shell before they even reach `jq`.

Comment: @deceze the shell doesn't interpret anything inside single quotes.

Comment: Tell that to my zsh…

Comment: Neither works, by the way. `echo '{"content":"\uD83E\uDD37"}' | jq -c .` on the other hand, does work (on bash, with `xpg_echo` off).

Comment: @deceze `echo` itself is expanding the strings. If you stored the raw JSON response in a file, there wouldn't be an issue. (Though you would still have the problem of the JSON response containing UTF-8 bytes, rather than proper Unicode code points.)